# Count the frequency of identical columns in a list of tidygraph objects in R?

Tags: r, tidygraph

I have a some tidygraph objects contained in a list. I am trying to count the frequency of columns (within the tidygraph nodes data) that are identical.

For example,

if I create some nodes and edge data, turn them into tidygraph objects, and put them in a list, like so:

```
library(tidygraph)

# create some node and edge data for the tbl_graph
nodes <- data.frame(name = c("x4", NA, NA),
                    val = c(1, 5, 2))
nodes2 <- data.frame(name = c("x4", NA, NA),
                    val = c(3, 2, 2))
nodes3 <- data.frame(name = c("x4", NA, NA),
                     val = c(5, 6, 7))
nodes4 <- data.frame(name = c("x4", "x2", NA, NA, "x1", NA, NA),
                     val = c(3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 7))
nodes5 <- data.frame(name= c("x1", "x2", NA),
                     val = c(7, 4, 2))
nodes6 <- data.frame(name = c("x1", "x2", NA),
                     val = c(2, 1, 3))

edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,1), to = c(2,3))
edges1 <- data.frame(from = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 5, 5),
                     to    = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7))

# create the tbl_graphs
tg   <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodes,  edges = edges)
tg_1 <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodes2, edges = edges)
tg_2 <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodes2, edges = edges)
tg_3 <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodes4, edges = edges1)
tg_4 <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodes5, edges = edges)
tg_5 <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodes6, edges = edges)


# put into list
myList <- list(tg, tg_1, tg_2, tg_3, tg_4, tg_5)
```

We can see that `tg`, `tg_1`, and `tg_2` all have identical `name` columns. Similarly, `tg_4` and `tg_5` have identical `name` columns in the node data.

I'm trying to come up with a way to count the frequency of tidygraph objects that have identical `name` columns. I would like to be able to return a list of the tidygraph objects with maybe another column added that displays the frequency.
In my case, the `val` column isn't important, so my desired output would look something like this:

```
 [[1]]
# A tbl_graph: 3 nodes and 2 edges
#
# A rooted tree
#
# Node Data: 3 × 2 (active)
  name  frequency
  <chr>     <dbl>
1 x4            3
2 NA            3
3 NA            3
#
# Edge Data: 2 × 2
   from    to
  <int> <int>
1     1     2
2     1     3

[[2]]
# A tbl_graph: 3 nodes and 2 edges
#
# A rooted tree
#
# Node Data: 3 × 2 (active)
  name  frequency
  <chr>     <dbl>
1 x1            2
2 x2            2
3 NA            2
#
# Edge Data: 2 × 2
   from    to
  <int> <int>
1     1     2
2     1     3

[[3]]
# A tbl_graph: 7 nodes and 6 edges
#
# A rooted tree
#
# Node Data: 7 × 2 (active)
  name  frequency
  <chr>     <dbl>
1 x4            1
2 x2            1
3 NA            1
4 NA            1
5 x1            1
6 NA            1
# … with 1 more row
#
# Edge Data: 6 × 2
   from    to
  <int> <int>
1     1     2
2     2     3
3     2     4
# … with 3 more rows
```

To be clear, in my above example, the `name` column containing `x4, NA, NA` appears 3 times in my original list of objects. Hence the frequency count of 3. Similarly, the `name` column equal to `x1, x2, NA` appears 2 times in `myList`, so it gets a frequency of 2... etc.

However, Im open to any clever suggestions as to the best way to return the frequency information.

Comment: To add a column to each can be done using `purrr::imap(myList, ~.x %>% mutate(frequency = 1:n()))` where `1:n()` can be replaced with the logic to obtain the frequency, manipulating a `.y` variable. But frankly, I fail to understand why the frequency in `tg` should be a series of 3s.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll give it a try. The logic as to why the 1st entry in my desired output has a frequency of 3 is because the `name` column is identical in 3 of the  tidygraph objects in my original list in my example. I think I could have made my desired output a bit clearer. I will edit the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `tidygraph` plays nicely with `tidyverse` we can use `dplyr` syntax directly to manipulate elements. To make the frequencies (probably not the right term for this), or series of decrementing occurrences, `group_by()` followed by a `n()` can be used. We can then rely on vector recycling to assign a value to a column of a list element, depending on its index `.y`.

```
freqs <- lapply(myList, function(x){
  x %>% 
     pull(name) %>%
     replace_na("..") %>%
     paste0(collapse = "")
}) %>%
  unlist(use.names = F) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  group_by(value) %>%
  mutate(val = n():1) %>%
  pull(val)

purrr::imap(l, ~.x %>% 
              mutate(frequency = freqs[.y]) %>% 
              select(name, frequency))
[[1]]
# Node Data: 3 x 2 (active)
  name  frequency
1 x4            3
2 NA            3
3 NA            3

# Edge Data: 2 x 2
   from    to
  <int> <int>
1     1     2
2     1     3

[[2]]
# Node Data: 3 x 2 (active)
  name  frequency
  <chr>     <int>
1 x4            2
2 NA            2
3 NA            2

# Edge Data: 2 x 2
   from    to
  <int> <int>
1     1     2
2     1     3

[[3]]
# Node Data: 3 x 2 (active)
  name  frequency
  <chr>     <int>
1 x4            1
2 NA            1
3 NA            1
```