# Remove duplicated elements from a list of tidygraph objects in R?

Tags: r, tidygraph

I have a list of tidygraph objects. Within the node data I have two columns, i.e., `name` and `frequency`. What I'm trying to do is remove any of the list elements (i.e., tidygraph objects) that are repeated more than once.  Hopefully my example can explain more:

To begin, I create some node/edge data, turn them into tidygraph objects and put them in a list:

```
library(tidygraph)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)


# create some node and edge data for the tbl_graph
nodes <- data.frame(name = c("x4", NA, NA),
                    val = c(1, 5, 2))
nodes2 <- data.frame(name = c("x4", NA, NA),
                     val = c(3, 2, 2))
nodes3 <- data.frame(name = c("x4", NA, NA),
                     val = c(5, 6, 7))
nodes4 <- data.frame(name = c("x4", "x2", NA, NA, "x1", NA, NA),
                     val = c(3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 7))
nodes5 <- data.frame(name= c("x1", "x2", NA),
                     val = c(7, 4, 2))
nodes6 <- data.frame(name = c("x1", "x2", NA),
                     val = c(2, 1, 3))

edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,1), to = c(2,3))
edges1 <- data.frame(from = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 5, 5),
                     to    = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7))

# create the tbl_graphs
tg   <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodes,  edges = edges)
tg_1 <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodes2, edges = edges)
tg_2 <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodes2, edges = edges)
tg_3 <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodes4, edges = edges1)
tg_4 <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodes5, edges = edges)
tg_5 <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodes6, edges = edges)


# put into list
myList <- list(tg, tg_1, tg_2, tg_3, tg_4, tg_5)
```

Then, I have this little function that tells me the frequency of each list element, based on the `name` columns. That is, if the column `name` is repeated/identical in multiple list elements, then the frequency is increased. So, in my example above, the `name` column in `tg` appears 3 times (identically in `tg`, `tg_1`, and `tg_2`) over my list... so it gets a frequency of 3.

I am then adding a `frequency` column to each list element and altering my original `myList` object. For example:

```
freqs <- lapply(myList, function(x){
  x %>% 
    pull(name) %>%
    replace_na("..") %>%
    paste0(collapse = "")
}) %>%
  unlist(use.names = F) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  group_by(value) %>%
  mutate(val = n():1) %>%
  pull(val)
  
  

newList <- purrr::imap(myList, ~.x %>% 
              mutate(frequency = freqs[.y]) %>% 
              select(name, frequency))
```

Looking at `newList` now returns:

```
> newList
[[1]]
# A tbl_graph: 3 nodes and 2 edges
#
# A rooted tree
#
# Node Data: 3 × 2 (active)
  name  frequency
  <chr>     <int>
1 x4            3
2 NA            3
3 NA            3
#
# Edge Data: 2 × 2
   from    to
  <int> <int>
1     1     2
2     1     3

[[2]]
# A tbl_graph: 3 nodes and 2 edges
#
# A rooted tree
#
# Node Data: 3 × 2 (active)
  name  frequency
  <chr>     <int>
1 x4            2
2 NA            2
3 NA            2
#
# Edge Data: 2 × 2
   from    to
  <int> <int>
1     1     2
2     1     3

[[3]]
# A tbl_graph: 3 nodes and 2 edges
#
# A rooted tree
#
# Node Data: 3 × 2 (active)
  name  frequency
  <chr>     <int>
1 x4            1
2 NA            1
3 NA            1
#
# Edge Data: 2 × 2
   from    to
  <int> <int>
1     1     2
2     1     3

[[4]]
# A tbl_graph: 7 nodes and 6 edges
#
# A rooted tree
#
# Node Data: 7 × 2 (active)
  name  frequency
  <chr>     <int>
1 x4            1
2 x2            1
3 NA            1
4 NA            1
5 x1            1
6 NA            1
# … with 1 more row
#
# Edge Data: 6 × 2
   from    to
  <int> <int>
1     1     2
2     2     3
3     2     4
# … with 3 more rows

[[5]]
# A tbl_graph: 3 nodes and 2 edges
#
# A rooted tree
#
# Node Data: 3 × 2 (active)
  name  frequency
  <chr>     <int>
1 x1            2
2 x2            2
3 NA            2
#
# Edge Data: 2 × 2
   from    to
  <int> <int>
1     1     2
2     1     3

[[6]]
# A tbl_graph: 3 nodes and 2 edges
#
# A rooted tree
#
# Node Data: 3 × 2 (active)
  name  frequency
  <chr>     <int>
1 x1            1
2 x2            1
3 NA            1
#
# Edge Data: 2 × 2
   from    to
  <int> <int>
1     1     2
2     1     3
```

So we can see that the `name` column with `x4, NA, NA` appears 3 times... but instead of adding the frequency to each.... I seem to be counting down the frequency (not intentional)... so, `x4, NA, NA` says it's frequency is 3, then 2 then 1.

I am trying to remove any of the duplicated list elements and keep just the element with the highest frequency. For example, my desired output would look like:

```
> newList
[[1]]
# A tbl_graph: 3 nodes and 2 edges
#
# A rooted tree
#
# Node Data: 3 × 2 (active)
  name  frequency
  <chr>     <int>
1 x4            3
2 NA            3
3 NA            3
#
# Edge Data: 2 × 2
   from    to
  <int> <int>
1     1     2
2     1     3

[[2]]
# A tbl_graph: 7 nodes and 6 edges
#
# A rooted tree
#
# Node Data: 7 × 2 (active)
  name  frequency
  <chr>     <int>
1 x4            1
2 x2            1
3 NA            1
4 NA            1
5 x1            1
6 NA            1
# … with 1 more row
#
# Edge Data: 6 × 2
   from    to
  <int> <int>
1     1     2
2     2     3
3     2     4
# … with 3 more rows

[[3]]
# A tbl_graph: 3 nodes and 2 edges
#
# A rooted tree
#
# Node Data: 3 × 2 (active)
  name  frequency
  <chr>     <int>
1 x1            2
2 x2            2
3 NA            2
#
# Edge Data: 2 × 2
   from    to
  <int> <int>
1     1     2
2     1     3
```

Here we can see that the elements with the duplicated frequencies have been removed... any suggestions as to how I could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comment on the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69998371/count-the-frequency-of-identical-columns-in-a-list-of-tidygraph-objects-in-r/69999389#69999389) would be sufficient motivation to change the answer. That said, slightly updating the code by `slice`-ing the first of the grouped tibble, possibly like this:

```
library(tidygraph) ; library(tidyverse)
freqs <- map(myList, function(x){
  x %>% 
    pull(name) %>%
    replace_na("..") %>%
    paste0(collapse = "")
}) %>%
  unlist(use.names = F) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(ids = 1:n()) %>%
  group_by(value) %>%
  mutate(val = n():1)

ids <- freqs %>% slice(1) %>% pull(ids)
freqs <- freqs %>% pull(val)

newList <- purrr::imap(myList, ~.x %>% 
                         mutate(frequency = freqs[.y]) %>% 
                         select(name, frequency))

newList[sort(ids)]

[[1]]
# A tbl_graph: 3 nodes and 2 edges
#
# A rooted tree
#
# Node Data: 3 x 2 (active)
  name  frequency
  <chr>     <int>
1 x4            3
2 NA            3
3 NA            3
#
# Edge Data: 2 x 2
   from    to
  <int> <int>
1     1     2
2     1     3

[[2]]
# A tbl_graph: 7 nodes and 6 edges
#
# A rooted tree
#
# Node Data: 7 x 2 (active)
  name  frequency
  <chr>     <int>
1 x4            1
2 x2            1
3 NA            1
4 NA            1
5 x1            1
6 NA            1
# ... with 1 more row
#
# Edge Data: 6 x 2
   from    to
  <int> <int>
1     1     2
2     2     3
3     2     4
# ... with 3 more rows

[[3]]
# A tbl_graph: 3 nodes and 2 edges
#
# A rooted tree
#
# Node Data: 3 x 2 (active)
  name  frequency
  <chr>     <int>
1 x1            2
2 x2            2
3 NA            2
#
# Edge Data: 2 x 2
   from    to
  <int> <int>
1     1     2
2     1     3
```